# Meteor client loses connection

Tags: meteor

I'm developing on my local machine, and every so often the browser client loses connection and can't reconnect without me manually restarting the browser and server. I don't see any errors in the server log.

OSX 10.8.4, Meteor 0.6.4.1. Google Chrome 28.0.1500.95

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

```
Meteor.status()
Object {status: "waiting", connected: false, retryCount: 2, retryTime: 1376450876245.0037}

...

Meteor.reconnect()
undefined
Meteor.status()
Object {status: "waiting", connected: false, retryCount: 11, retryTime: 1376500323062.412}
```

mongod

```
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.899 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=78417 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=Kyles-MacBook.local
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.900 [initandlisten]
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.900 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.900 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.2
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.901 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.901 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin Kyles-MacBook.local 12.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.901 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.901 [initandlisten] options: {}
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.901 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.902 dbexit:
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.902 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.902 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.902 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.902 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.902 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.902 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.902 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.903 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.903 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.903 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
Thu Aug 15 12:14:59.903 dbexit: really exiting now
    enter code here
```

Comment: A bit more of information about your env (system, meteor version, browser type/version) would be helpful. Furthermore: What exactly do you mean with "looses connection" - are socket connections failing or reconnecting to the server via http?

Comment: @matthias OSX 10.8.4, Meteor 0.6.4.1. Google Chrome 28.0.1500.95. Once disconnected it never reconnects. Just hangs there at "waiting" indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor uses a data-on-the-wire principle. So it can load in the browser and needs a connection to the internet to maintain the 'liveness' of the data.

So when you lose connectivity its built smart to try and reconnect. So at first it'll try to reconnect is small intervals.

What you see there is that meteor is retrying to connect to the server

- `status` is its waiting to retry. `connected` is `false`
- `retryCount` shows how many times it has tried to connect again
- `retryTime` shows the last time or next time it tried/will try to connect (not sure which it is)

There aren't any errors at this point but meteor will build up a que of whatever you do (changes to the collection, etc) and then as soon as it connects it will commit these to the server.

Instead of refreshing the browser you could use `Meteor.reconnect()` to connect to the server if you don't want to wait for the next reconnection interval. This way you also won't lose any data that's not been committed to the server.

If this happens when you're absolutely sure that there is a good connection in between you need to have a look at your server's console. It is likely that something is making it crash/locking up the main thread. Perhaps you're doing a blocking intensive task? (i.e from large collections, a CPU intensive task?)

Comment: Meteor.reconnect just returns an "undefined".

Meteor.reconnect()
undefined
Meteor.status()
Object {status: "waiting", connected: false, retryCount: 11, retryTime: 1376500323062.412}


I'm positive there is a good connection, the server's console offers no information regarding any crashes/locks. I'm guessing something is blocking, but I don't believe I am doing anything out of the ordinary, it's a very basic application with only a dozen records. Is there some way to get a verbose output from the console?

Comment: Meteor.reconnect is supposed to return undefined it doesn't return a value but it attempts to reconnect to the server. Could you show a bit more of your app to try find what might be causing it to block. Do you have a possibility of an infinite loop in your loops?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had set up my routes incorrectly. Using Meteor-router, I configured my routes.js file according to an outdated tutorial. I rewrote the routes based on the meteor-router documentation and this cleared things up.